# How to Perform Panel Unit Root Test Using cipstest Function of plm Package and Panel Cointegration Test Using pedroni99m Function of pco Package

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I'm trying to calculate two tests on my panel data. However, following the documentations for the various packages and respective functions, I obtain errors. My search online for possible remedies has not being fruitful.

First, I want to perform a second generation panel unit root test on a panel data using the `cipstest` function in the `plm` package but I obtain an error: **Error in approx(nintv, cvals[nintl:ninth, tintl, i], n = max(nintv) -  : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate**

The code I tried using to calculate the test is:

```
Y1CT <- cipstest(AT$y1, lags = 2, type = c("trend"), model = c("cmg"), truncated = FALSE)
```

Second, I want to perform a panel cointegration test on the same panel data using the `pedroni99m` function in the `pco` package but I obtain an error: **Error in 2:dim(X)[3] : NA/NaN argument**

The code I tried using to calculate the test is:

```
pedroni99m(PCOY1)
```

prior to using the above code, `pedroni99m(PCOY1)`, I created a new set of dataframes, corresponding to each dependent variable and its' independent and control variables using the following codes:

```
PCOY1 <- data.frame(AT$y1, AT$x1, AT$x2, AT$x3, AT$x4, AT$x5, AT$x6, AT$x7, AT$z1, AT$z2, AT$z3, AT$z4)
                   

PCOY2 <- data.frame(AT$y2, AT$x1, AT$x2, AT$x3, AT$x4, AT$x5, AT$x6, AT$x7, AT$z1, AT$z2, AT$z3, AT$z4)


PCOY3 <- data.frame(AT$y3, AT$x1, AT$x2, AT$x3, AT$x4, AT$x5, AT$x6, AT$x7, AT$z1, AT$z2, AT$z3, AT$z4)


PCOY4 <- data.frame(AT$y4, AT$x1, AT$x2, AT$x3, AT$x4, AT$x5, AT$x6, AT$x7, AT$z1, AT$z2, AT$z3, AT$z4)
```

Attached is a link to my data set, https://www.dropbox.com/s/wazb9kr8wictwjg/mds.csv?dl=0 ,(It is saved as a `.csv` file).

The description of the data set is as follows:

1. Each `y` is a **dependent variable**
2. Each `x` is an **independent variable**
3. Each `z` is a **control variable**

I declared the data as a panel data as follows:

```
AT <- pdata.frame(mds,index = c('ccode','year'))
```

Would be more than glad to receive your thoughtful considerations.